# Help evaluating or approximating this integral

Tags: integration, approximation, indefinite-integrals

For a thermodynamics project I'm working on, I need to evaluate this integral:

$\int \frac{(a-bx)(x-c)^d}{x^3}dx$, where $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are all positive constants.

I tried evaluating it on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28a-bx%29%28x-c%29%5Ed/%28x%5E3%29), but it's giving a solution based on the hypergeometric series. Is there any other way of evaluating this integral? Or are there any good approximations of this integral in terms of elementary functions of $x$? I'm not looking for numerical solutions, but rather analytic solutions/approximations.

Comment: You can make a taylor expansion and integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the binomial theorem?

$$(x-c)^d=\sum_{i=0}^{d}\binom{d}{i}x^{d-i}(-c)^i.$$

Then, you'll have 
$$\int\sum_{i=0}^{d}a\binom{d}{i}x^{d-3-i}(-c)^idx-\int\sum_{i=0}^{d}b\binom{d}{i}x^{d-2-i}(-c)^idx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Expand $ (x-c)^d $ using [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem) and the function will simplify to a finite sum of powers of x, which (given you remember to treat the $1\over x$ case separately) is trivial to integrate.